# O que significa o nome da classe em super().__init__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tipagem, herança, construtor

Qual o funcionamento do nome das classes inseridas dentro dos parênteses do construtor `__init__( )`, nas classes `Telefones`, `TiposTelefone` e `Agenda`?

> Esse é somente um trecho de código do Cap.10 do livro "Introdução a Programação com Python" do Autor: Nilo Ney Coutinho Menezes.

```
class ListaUnica:

    def __init__(self, elem_class):
        self.lista = []
        self.elem_class = elem_class
    ...


class Telefone:

    def __init__(self, numero, tipo=None):
        self.numero = numero
        self.tipo = tipo
    ...


class Telefones(ListaUnica):

    def __init__(self):
        # Não entendo QUAL O FUNCIONAMENTO da classe Telefone
        # dentro do __init__ do método super(). Até onde estudei
        # sobre POO, a função construtora é usada para
        # inserir parâmetros, (ou não), para a classe, e normalmente
        # HERDAMOS ESSES PARÂMETROS da superclasse (no caso,
        # da classe ListaUnica) usando o método built-in super(), 
        # mas aqui nesse caso, inserimos a classe
        # Telefone no lugar de onde seria normalmente inserido parâmetros
        # que herdariamos da classe pai (no caso, ListaUnica),
        # acabei ficando sem entender o fluxo do código, 
        # poderia me explicar o que acontece com o código na linha abaixo...       
        super().__init__(Telefone)


class DadoAgenda:

    def __init__(self, nome):
        self.nome = nome
        self.telefones = Telefones()

    ...


class TiposTelefone(ListaUnica):

    def __init__(self):
        # não entendo qual o funcionamento da classe TiposTelefone
        # dentro do __init__ do metodo super() tbm!!!.
        super().__init__(TipoTelefone)


class Agenda(ListaUnica):

    def __init__(self):
        # não entendo qual o funcionamento da classe DadoAgenda
        # dentro do __init__ do metodo super() tbm!!!.
        super().__init__(DadoAgenda) 
        self.tiposTelefone = TiposTelefone()

    ...
```

Comment: Você está falando do `self, elem_class`?

Comment: Não, estou falando desse nome Telefone em: super().__init__(Telefone), não sei qual o seu funcionamento no código!!!

Comment: O que quer dizer com funcionamento?

Comment: eu quero dizer é que eu não consigo entender o pq e o que faz o nome de uma classe (no caso, o nome da classe Telefone) estar dentro  dos parenteses do  __init__ do método super(), pq até onde eu estudei POO, o metodo super() serve somente para herdar os parâmetros da classe pai (no caso, da classe ListaUnica), e no lugar de onde se faz isso (herdar parâmetros) está o nome de uma classe, eu não entendi o pq disso...

Comment: Com o `super().__init__()` você invocará o método `__init__` de `ListaUnica`, que recebe como parâmetro `elem_class`. O nome da classe aqui será o valor de `elem_class`

Comment: ok, até aí tudo bem, mas num deveria ter sido inserido o nome elem_class ao invés de Telefone, assim: super().__init__(elem_class) ?, eu não sei pq q foi feito assim: super().__init__(Telefone), pq até onde sei sobre herança, os atributos são manipulados somente entre a classe pai (classe ListaUnica) e a classe filha (Telefones), então pq de uma classe que nao tem nada a ver com as duas (ListaUnica e Telefone) ter sido configurada no __init__() do método super()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi `ListaUnica` espera um tipo como parâmetro para fazer algum tipo de verificação se a lista está recebendo sempre um elemento do mesmo tipo. Na verdade o código está ruim e não atende esse requisito muito bem, mas de alguma forma tem essa ideia.

Geralmente isto é necessário para garantir que a lista é homogênea e portanto coerente, não é uma lista de qualquer coisa. O que mostra que Python não é a linguagem mais adequada para isso, apesar de funcionar.

Na verdade acho este código ruim porque isso deveria ser uma composição onde a agenda deveria ter, entre outras coisas um lista de telefones. Uma agenda, e este deveria ser o nome mais apropriado da classe, não é uma lista única, ela tem uma lista única. Portanto é mais um material tentando forçar OOP onde não cabe.

Então neste código torno, quando chama o `super()` está chamando o construtor da classe mãe, no caso a `ListaUnica` e passando para ele o argumento que ela espera, que é um tipo. Não é um dado comum, é um dado que representa um tipo declarado no seu código, no caso o `Telefone`. Ele usará o tipo como informação para verificar se está tudo ok.

Espero que entenda a diferença entre o tipo e o objeto em si. Se não entendeu, volte 3 casas no tabuleiro para aprender os conceitos corretamente antes de ver exemplos, e assim poder julgar o que está acontecendo.

Comment: É exatamente isso que vc disse Maniero, a classe ListaUnica está configurada para aceitar somente objetos de um determinado tipo, na verdade esse é só um trecho de todo o código que o livro propôs para entendermos, mas ainda não consigo entender o funcionamento dessa linha: super().__init__(Telefone), mas tudo bem, obrigado pela ajuda, vou ver se consigo entender estudando o código de novo, valew!!!

Comment: Na verdade poderia ser um pattern legal - mas o tipo das subclasses da ListaUnica deveria ser declarado num atributo de classe. Do jeito que está, está bem ruinzinho mesmo.