# Método construtor em classes com herança

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Utilizando Python3, como ficaria o método construtor da classe **Z**?

```
class W:
    def __init__(self, atributo1):
        self.atributo1 = atributo1

    def metodo1(self):
        print("Metodo1")

class X(W):
    def __init__(self, atributo1, atributo2):
        super().__init__(atributo1)
        self.atributo2 = atributo2

class Y(W):
    def __init__(self, atributo1, atributo3):
        super().__init__(atributo1)
        self.atributo3 = atributo3

    def metodo2(self):
        print("Metodo2")

class Z(X, Y):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem um problema valioso nas mãos.

Essa questão é o que chamamos de [problema do diamante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233728/5878) e ocorre na herança múltipla quando uma classe herda de duas classes que herdam de uma mesma classe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o problema é justamente esse: os atributos de A devem ser passados para D através de B ou de C? De ambos não dá, senão ficariam duplicados. No seu caso, você possui o campo `atributo1` em `W`. Qual deverá ser o valor final de `atributo1`, o que eu passar pela classe `X` ou pela classe `Y`?

O problema se agrava ainda mais porque você fez mal uso da função `super`. Isso possivelmente se dá porque você não entendeu bem o que ela faz.

- [Python chamada super() em classe que não implementa herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320217/5878)
- [O que significa o nome da classe em super().__init__()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318055/5878)
- [Diferença entre Pai.__init(self) e super(Pai, self).__init__()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103570/5878)

No seu caso, a classe `Z` não possui um método inicializador (`__init__`) e o MRO define que o nome do método será resolvido primeiro em `X`. Lembre-se que estamos trabalhando com uma instância de `Z`. Assim, o método `X.__init__` será executado primeiro.

O método `X.__init__` chama a função `super`, que nos retorna um objeto *proxy* para a próxima classe na sequência definida pelo MRO da nossa instância. Como trabalhamos como uma instância de `Z` e estamos na classe `X`, a próxima classe na sequência definida pela MRO será `Y`. Ou seja, quando você faz `super().__init__(atributo1)` em `X`, você chamará o inicializador de `Y`. WTF?

Percebe a confusão? Uma classe `X` que herda apenas de `W` está invocando um método em `Y`. Mas calma, não é o bicho de sete cabeças (mas é o de múltiplas cabeças :D).

Se você ler a [documentação da função `super`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#super), que acredito que já tenha lido, verá que ela funciona bem com múltipla herança quando todas as classes possuem a mesma assinatura. Mas como possuir a mesma assinatura se cada classe demanda parâmetros diferentes? Aí é você, como desenvolvedor e autor do projeto, que deve definir o que deve ser feito ou não. Faça analisando as consequências. Uma das formas é utilizar o parâmetro coringa `**kwargs` e utilizar apenas parâmetros nomeados. Algo como:

```
class W:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.atributo1 = kwargs['atributo1']

    def metodo1(self):
        print("Metodo1")

class X(W):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.atributo2 = kwargs['atributo2']

class Y(W):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.atributo3 = kwargs['atributo3']
```

Assim, todas as classes terão a mesma assinatura em seus inicializadores e você poderá fazer:

```
z = Z(atributo1=1, atributo2=2, atributo3=3)

print('Atributo 1:', z.atributo1)
print('Atributo 2:', z.atributo2)
print('Atributo 3:', z.atributo3)
```

Obtendo:

```
Atributo 1: 1
Atributo 2: 2
Atributo 3: 3
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Mas pode me ajudar a entender melhor porque fiz mal uso da função `super`? Qual seria a forma correta de implementar?

Comment: @L.WD eu expliquei isso na resposta. O `super` busca a próxima classe da MRO com base na instância atual, não na classe. Então, na classe X, ao invés dela chamar o método em W, chamará de Y - que não tem nada a ver com X. Leia mais sobre o problema do diamante e MRO.

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado. Eu estudei um pouco mais à respeito do MRO e utilizando `print(Z.mro())` consegui "visualizar" melhor a sequência definida e em que classe aconteceria a busca... muito bom. Mas minha dúvida inicial perdura: como ficaria então o construtor da classe Z? Ficaria assim: 

`class Z(X, Y): def __init__(self, **kwargs): super().__init__(**kwargs)`

Comment: Se você fizer os inicializadores como coloquei por último, nem precisaria de um método `__init__` em `Z`. Mas se precisar, é só seguir a mesma ideia das outras classes.

Comment: Fiz como escrevi no comentário anterior e funcionou perfeitamente... Pelo que entendi então, se não fosse o caso de um "problema do diamante" e, no meu exemplo, não existisse a classe W (e consequentemente as classes X e Y não herdassem nada de ninguém) o construtor da classe Z poderia ser: `def __init__(self, atributo1, atributo2): super().__init__(atributo1) super(X, self).__init__(atributo2)`

Comment: Já que utilizando o `super(X, self).__init__` eu consigo "direcionar" onde buscar o próximo construtor... correto?